# Chrome extension: upon fetch request within a popup element, where may I see endpoint request's details?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am currently calling an endpoint within a popup element that contains a [React application](https://github.com/sivertschou/snow-extension) (github link):

App.tsx

```js
const App = () => {
  const [blah, setBlah ] = React.useState<any>('nothing');

  React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/12/').then(response => response.json()).then(data => setBlah(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    {JSON.stringify(blah)}
    <Button/>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I can see the response has been successful in my popup, but cannot see its request details within the browser console's network tab. Likewise, I haven't been able to see it within the background page console as well. Any ideas to where I may find the endpoint request details?

[image]

Comment: Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.